# Why there's no Request.Content in ASP .NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

How to get access to content data?

I can get Request.ContentLength , ContentType, but Content I can't.

I tried to add [FromBody] attribute before my string parameter, but it returns null anyway.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string CreateItemType([System.Web.Http.FromBody] string json) // still returns null
    {
       var Content = Request.Content; // Error: 'HttpRequestBase' doesn't have a definition for 'Content'
       if (IsAuthorized(Request) == false) return "Authorization Error"; ...
```

Are there some ways to access sent data?

My app for sending data:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(Link);
            request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", ApiKey);
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            var MyResponse = await client.SendAsync(request);
            MyResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            content = await MyResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
```

P.S: I could pass all the parameters into the request link, but my JSON-string is too big.

Comment: You already got the content in the `json` parameter. Why are you trying to read it again from the `Request` object?

Comment: Because I get null.

Comment: I would think the question should be "why is it null" and "what do i need to change so it isn't null".

Comment: My main target is access sent data. And I don't know how.

Comment: Could you share us your json that you are passing to the body of the request? Maybe you have some issues with format? Anyway, try to wrap your parameter with DTO class.